# Proper way to include headers + custom server-side .js in express.js / node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, template-engine

I am creating a small-to-medium sized data-driven HTML site from developers for developers in our company. The idea is to have a [node.js v0.12+](https://nodejs.org/) / [express v4+](http://expressjs.com) server running which provides some helper functions to access a large database.

I would like to allow other developers with minimum effort to pull the repository from Git, create a custom *view* (which should be a a partial HTML page-body) and commit back, e.g., something like this:

```
app/        
    views/
        common.view1/
            module.html
            module.js
        common.view2/
        team1.view2/
        ...

    common/
        header.html
        footer.html

    main.html   (automatically finds files under views)
```

What I am looking for is a proven, non-hackish solution or module (e.g., >1k stars on Github) so that with minimal code would allow me to do something like this in my node's `app.js`:

```
xxx.templatify('*.html');
xxx.registerFunction('helper', returnString);    
expressApp.usetemplateengine(xxx);
```

And in `views/<someview>/module.html`:

```
<% include('common/header'); %>
<h2>Hello <% helper('world'); %> h2>
```

I wouldn't mind if the `include` could be defined server-side. The modules.html should however stay vanilla HTML as much as possible.

My question: How can I do this and is there an obvious standard solution I am missing?

I looked a little into [ejs](http://www.embeddedjs.com), [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) and friends, but most seem to impose their own completely new syntax (e.g, Jade), or I would have to register every file individually.

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars is the closest I can think of that closely resembles html, but you will still need to map routes to .handlebars files. Thinking out aloud, you could build a mapping helper method to do that for you, but I have not tried that approach as of to date.